# prove that the following interesting problem

Tags: analysis

Let $L^{\infty}=L^{\infty}(m)$, where $m$ is the lebesgue measure on [0,1].Show that there is no non zero bounded linear functional $\Lambda$ on $L^{\infty} $ that is 0 on $C([0,1])$, and that therefore there is no  $g\in L^1(m)$ that satisfies $\Lambda(f)=\int_{[0,1]}fg dm$  for every $f\in L^{\infty}$.Thus $(L^{\infty})*\neq L^1$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Show", "Prove", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I am missing something, but surely I can choose the subspace
$V = \{f+ \lambda 1_{[{1\over 2},1]} | f \in C[0,1], \lambda \in \mathbb{R} \}$
and define $\Lambda:V \to \mathbb{R}$ by $\Lambda(g) = \lim_{x \downarrow {1 \over 2}} g(x) - \lim_{x \uparrow {1 \over 2}} g(x)$. Since 
$\Lambda(f+\lambda 1_{[{1\over 2},1]}) = \lambda$, we have $\ker \Lambda = C[0,1]$ and $\|\Lambda\|_V = 1$. Now extend $\Lambda$ to $L^\infty(m)$ using Hahn Banach.

It should be clear that the above $\Lambda$ cannot be written as $\Lambda(f) = \int fg dm$. If $\int f g dm = 0$ for all $f \in C[0,1]$, then we must have $g(x) = 0$ ae. x[$m$], which would imply that $\Lambda = 0$.

Comment: Could you explain how you got $g = 0$ a.e. $[m]$?

Comment: @epsilon-emperor It is a little more involved that I originally thought. There may be a simpler proof, but one escapes me now. Extend $g$ to the real line by setting it to zero everywhere. Let $\hat{g}$ be the Fourier transform of $g$, the above shows that $\hat{g} = 0$ and the (Fourier transform) inversion theorem shows that $g = 0$ ae.

Comment: Thank you! There is in fact a simpler proof. Found it sometime after posting the above comment. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3698027/if-g-in-l10-1-satisfies-int-0-1-fgdx-0-for-all-f-in-c0-1-then