# If $g\in L^1[0,1]$ satisfies $\int_{[0,1]} fg~dx=0$ for all $f\in C[0,1]$ then $g=0$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $g\in L^1[0,1]$ satisfies $\int_{[0,1]} fg~dx=0$ for all $f\in C[0,1]$. (Here, we are considering Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$.
) Then do we necessarily have $g=0$?

I am trying to show that "not" every bounded linear functional on $L^\infty[0,1]$ is of the form $f\mapsto \int_{[0,1]} fh~dx$ for some $h\in L^1[0,1]$, and if the above question is true, then I am done, but  I can't see whethere it is indeed true.

Comment: @SahibaArora Yes, sure.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/352863/proof-of-the-du-bois-reymond-lemma-by-approximation

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$ is dense in $L^1[0,1]$ with respect to the $L^1$ norm?

Comment: @h3fr43nd Yes I do

Comment: Okay then I think I know how to do it :) will write up an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not yet an answer but rather a proof idea. To make notation a little simpler we will simply write $L^1$ instead of $L^1[0,1]$. So suppose now, that $g \in L^1$ with $$\int fg dx = 0$$ for all $f \in \mathcal{C}[0,1]$. The key to prove the result is to prove, that by denseness of $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$ in $L^1$ there exists a bounded sequence $\{f_n\} \subset \mathcal{C}[0,1]$, i.e. $\sup \|f_n\|_\infty < \infty$, such that $f_n \xrightarrow{L^1} sgn(g)$. Indeed, if that is the case, then from the proof of the Riesz-Fischer completeness theorem for $L^p$ spaces, we know, that there exists a subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}$ so that $f_{n_k} \to sgn(g)$ pointwise. But then by construction we have $$\underbrace{|f_{n_k}g-sgn(g)g|}_{\to 0} \leq |g| \sup \|f_n\|_\infty + |g|$$ So by the Dominated convergence Theorem $$\int |g| dx = \int sgn(g)g dx = \lim \int f_{n_k}g dx = 0$$ Thus $g = 0$ a.e.

Comment: By denseness of $C[0,1]$ in $L^1$ I see that we  can choose a sequence  $\{f_n\}\subset C[0,1]$ such that $f_n\to \text{sgn}(g)$ in $L^1$. But how can we assume that $\text{sup}||f_n||_{\infty}<\infty$?

Comment: For your key result, pick an arbitrary sequence $h_n \in C[0,1]$ such that $h_n \to \operatorname{sgn}(g)$ a.e. (possible by density of that set in $L^1$). Let $f_n(x) = \max\{-2, \min\{h_n(x),2\}\}$. Then $f_n$ is continuous, converges to $\operatorname{sgn}(g)$ a.e. and satisfies $\sup_n \|f_n\|_\infty \leq 2$. Finally, by the DCT you can conclude that $f_n \to \operatorname{sgn}(g)$ in $L^1$ also (with a constant as a dominating function since the measure space is finite).

Comment: @RhysSteele I was missing that $-1\leq \text{sgn}g\leq 1$. Thanks.